# unexpected end of file if and redirection input

Tags: shell, centos7

i want make shell script for updating file from client with ftp server when date of file on client not same with date of file on ftp server the script will download automatically but i always got unexpected end of file.

this my script :

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define FTP server details
FTP_HOST="host"
FTP_USER="ftp_user"
FTP_PASS="ftp_pass"
REMOTE_FILE="file.text"
LOCAL_DIR="/home"
LOCAL_FILE="$LOCAL_DIR/$REMOTE_FILE"

# Check if local file exists and is up-to-date with the file on the FTP server
if [ -f $LOCAL_FILE ]
 then
  # Get the modification time of the local file
  LOCAL_MTIME=$(stat -c %Y $LOCAL_FILE)

  # Connect to FTP server and get the modification time of the remote file
  FTP_MTIME=$(ftp -n $FTP_HOST <<END_SCRIPT
  quote USER $FTP_USER
  quote PASS $FTP_PASS
  cd script/
  ls -l $REMOTE_FILE
  quit
END_SCRIPT
  | awk '{print $6" "$7" "$8}')

  # Compare the modification times and download the latest file if necessary
  if [ "$LOCAL_MTIME" -lt "$(date -d "$FTP_MTIME" +%s)" ]
   then
    # Remove the old local file
    rm $LOCAL_FILE
    # Connect to FTP server and download the latest file
    ftp -n $FTP_HOST <<END_SCRIPT
    quote USER $FTP_USER
    quote PASS $FTP_PASS
    cd script/
    get $REMOTE_FILE $LOCAL_DIR
    quit
END_SCRIPT
    echo "File downloaded successfully."
  else
    echo "File is up-to-date."
  fi
else
  # Connect to FTP server and download the file
  ftp -n $FTP_HOST <<END_SCRIPT
  quote USER $FTP_USER
  quote PASS $FTP_PASS
  cd script/
  get $REMOTE_FILE $LOCAL_DIR
  quit
END_SCRIPT
  echo "File downloaded successfully."
fi
```

anyone can help me what wrong with my code?

Comment: You did not say, which command in your script produces the mentioned error message.

Comment: What have you tried so far to find the issue?